# Next.JS 13 Build Error (failed to process) on 13.5.5

Tags: build, next.js13

I'm using Next.JS 13 to make an admin dashboard for my company and I'm running into a few errors. Maybe someone can help me.

I've been developing the dashboard with v13.4.5 without any build issues. The issue I have with this version is many of my colleagues run into unresponsive pages in the dashboard. Obviously, being the developer this doesn't happen to me. I suspect it has to do with RAM usage being high in the new app directory. This suspicion comes from having quite an extensive app made with the pages router where we haven't had any issues with unresponsive pages.

When I saw the 13.5 update claiming 40% less memory usage I wanted to update, but the build fails as you can see in the image below. The build error just says "failed to process" which doesn't leave me much room to debug.

The Breadcumbs file that it's unable to process hasn't been changed in 14 months and has worked fine until now.

[Build error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YON03.png)

Built with Next.JS 13.4, everything fine.
Updated to 13.5 to try and fix unresponsive pages.
Built with Next.JS 13.5, build fails.